# Exclude -ObjC from some files - Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, google-analytics, admob

I have added -ObjC to "Other linking flags" under Build Settings in my Xcode project to be able to use Admob in my application. But, when I try to install Google Analytics - i get an error like this:

_OBJC_CLASS_$_GAI", referenced from:

When i removed -ObjC from Other Linking Flags and removed the AdMob files, everything worked fine. My question is, is there a way to exclude the analytics files from being affected by -ObjC in other linking flags?

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, you can add compiler flags on a file-by-file basis.

1. Open Xcode, and navigate to Project Editor > Build Phases > Compile Sources
2. Hold the <kbd>command</kbd> key and select each file with which you'd like to flag.
3. Double-click on the "Compiler Flags" portion (right-hand side) of the table
4. Add the `-ObjC` flag.
5. Compile!

Source: [iOS Developer Library: Controlling How an Individual File is Compiled](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/Adding%20a%20Compiler%20Flag%20to%20a%20File.html)